# Why is 0 an exception for to_char(0,'B9999')?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

What makes the number 0 an exception to Oracle to_char(number,'B9999') mask?
In this query 0 doesn't print at all.

How can I left pad all my numbers including 0 with spaces? 
Is `lpad()` the only alternative?

```
select to_char(0,'B09999') as num_fmt from dual union all
select to_char(0,'B9999') as num_fmt from dual  union all
select to_char(300,'B9999') as num_fmt from dual  union all
select to_char(-300,'B9999') as num_fmt from dual ;
```

Comment: `B` - **`Returns blanks for the integer part of a fixed-point number when the integer part is zero (regardless of zeros in the format model)`** From [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char(yourVal,'999')` format model to get left padded blanks for integers of three digits ( *Leading zeros are blank, except for a zero value* ).

If you need more, than raise the number of nines upto number of digits within your integer values :

```
select to_char(0,'999') as num_fmt from dual union all
select to_char('00','999')         from dual union all
select to_char('016','999')        from dual union all
select to_char(17,'999')           from dual union all
select to_char(314,'999')          from dual union all
select to_char(-314,'999')         from dual;

NUM_FMT
-------
      0
      0
     16
     17
    314
   -314
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=812e5c803469822eeac929aa7439eb62)</kbd>